# PHP CodeIgniter layout Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a very specific problem with the layout
Iam using the PHP, MVC CodeIgniter framework

I have a home page layout where there is left navigation withe following links with fade-in and fade-out effect.

Iam loading all the data from a home controller for these menus. All the data is from a single table
except for current_affairs which Iam loading it as a separate partial or html

Followin is the code snippet I have.

```
<div class="parrent pull-left">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">                        
<li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab"class="analistic><a></li> </ul>                
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="home1">
<p><?php echo $result -> home1?></p>
<p><?php =current_affairs ?></p>
</div>
```

Now Iam adding another new page which is the "local_news" page which will be from another method in  the same controller
I need the same left navigation in here as well. But the body content is different here. In that case if have a separate view 
for local_news and load both of them they are loading one after the other. which is not correct.
 Is there a way to display local news just like home,about ie, within the nav

Any help on this would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already discovered that you are loading the same thing twice. In local news just load the content instead of the whole page. Moreover, Its not clear what you are doing in the controller. But "YES" there are many ways to solve the problem. The way to follow is depended on the way you are organizing your things.